# How to puppetize frontend javascript configuration

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, puppet

We have have a javascript application and use puppet to automate deployments of that and our backend software. I was wondering about practices for handling different deployment environments on javascript. Typically we have a handful of things that need to be configured differently like access keys for things like facebook, backend urls of our own REST APIs, whether or not HTTPS is used, etc.

In a backend system, you would put such configuration in a properties file and use puppet to configure this at deployment time. For the frontend the problem is that we have a build server that compiles our coffeescript and other web assets and then packages things up as an RPM which is what we then deploy as part of our puppet run. The problem is that any configuration needs to be added before the build step since you can't actually access the file system and making a separate request just to fetch configuration is also not very desirable.

The best I can come up with involves basically doing some sed commands on the minified file post package install in puppet. This feels clumsy and I was wondering if someone has come up with a better solution for this.

Comment: Perhaps you can have a set of js files for declaring configuration, and use them as puppet templates, so puppet can inject the variables at build-time?

Comment: makes sense but I'd like to not make the extra request ideally

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "extra request", but your build server can apply a puppet manifest as part of the build deployment process.

Comment: I mean the browser would have to ask for the javascript file with the config separately from the minified javascript that we are serving, which is just one request. The other option is indeed to execute some string replacement logic at deploy time.